# tslint: no-object-mutation while building Object with reduce

Tags: javascript, typescript-typings, tslint

I want to build an object using `reduce` in this way:

```
const result = [1, 2].reduce((partialResult, actualValue) => {
    // define someKey and someValue
    partialResult[someKey] = someValue;
    return partialResult
}, {});
```

However, I'm getting the following tslint error:

```
Modifying properties of existing object not allowed. (no-object-mutation)
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Just FWIW, `reduce` serves no useful purpose there. It would be simpler to read and maintain with a simple loop.

Comment: You're using the same key each time, so the object will only ever have one property (using the key and the last value). The end result of the above is effectively `const result = {[someKey]: 2};` I assume the key does vary from one loop iteration to the next...?

Comment: `sameKey` and `someValue` changes according to `actualValue` + other irrelevant factors for the question.

Comment: Good good. :-) It would be useful to show a [mcve] version of that variation in the question so both the question and -- critically -- its answers are unambiguous.

Answer (score 2):

Either modify the code so that you're not mutating the object, which means you'll have to copy it each time:

```
const result = [1, 2].reduce((partialResult, actualValue) => {
    return {
      ...partialResult,
      [someKey]: someValue,
    }
}, {});
```

Or disable the lint rule (either for this specific line if you like the lint rule in general, or globally if you think it's an unnecessary restriction)

Comment: I see this as a very low performant solution or not really solving the problem.

Comment: I agree this is not optimized for performance. Repeatedly copying the object is wasteful and inefficient. As for it solving the problem, what problem are you trying to solve? You mentioned a lint error, i mentioned the two ways to fix it: don't mutate in a reduce, or don't have the lint rule. If you have additional requirements, please include them.

Comment: @justHelloWorld - How exactly does this not solve the problem? Separately: Is this a hyper-performance-critical part of your code? That is, do you have a known performance problem that's down to this loop? Because while it bothers me as much as the next guy to create and throw away objects, JavaScript engines are **incredibly** fast at doing it, particularly short-lived ones like this. The odds it causes a problem for your page/app are near zero.

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
const result = [1, 2].reduce(
    (partialResult, actualValue) => Object.assign({}, partialResult, {[someKey]: someValue]}), {});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) to create the object all-at-once (as far as your code is concerned) rather than mutating or copying the object:

```js
const someKey = "foo";
const result = Object.fromEntries(
  [1, 2].map(value => [someKey + value, value])
//                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^---- see my comment on the question and
//                                         note below
);
console.log(result);
```

`fromEntries` creates an object from an array of entries, where each entry is a `[key, value]` array.

Note that I've used `someKey + value` as the key because you haven't said how you get the key, and I assume you're not just using the **same** key every time, since as I commented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58203723/tslint-no-object-mutation-while-building-object-with-reduce/58203842#comment102785971_58203723), if you were you'd be replacing the property value every time if you did and end up with an object with a single property, making the entire loop pointless.